# Basic bundling of CDN in debug mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, bundle, cdn

Using the following:

`bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myBundle", "//cdn.com/myscript.js").Include("~/Scripts/myscript.js"));`

I can load from a CDN path in production, and fall back to a local copy of `myscript.js` in debug mode.

Great, but I don't want to do this - I want to load from the CDN path all the time, even in debug mode.

I tried supplying a CDN path in the `Include` method but I get an error since it needs to be a relative path (makes sense).

How can I load from the CDN permanently via bundling (regardless of 'mode')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this code in `Application_Start()`

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Comment: This was the problem, this had been added conditional on it being *not* release mode. Thank you.